# How would I print the sum of two numbers by using different parameters names in a function

Tags: c++, function, parameters

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void sum(int x,int y);

void sum(int a,int b)
{
    int a,b;
    int sum;
    cout<<"Enter Two numbers "<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    sum=a+b;
}

int main()
{
    int z=Sum(a,b)
    cout<<"Sum is "<<z<<endl;
}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong. It is giving me some errors for parameters.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message(s).

Comment: In `sum(int a, int b)`, *a* and *b* are already parameters to your function. Trying to redefine them inside the function gives an error, of course, it's illogical to do that. Also, if you want to actually *return* something from that function, you should use a [return statement](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_function_return.asp). Secondly, in your `main()` function, *a* and *b* are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here:

- You're attempting to call `Sum` which does not exist.  You should be calling `sum`.
- The values you're passing to the function do not exist.  There are no variables called `a` or `b` at the point where the function is called.
- The function is declared to not return a value (i.e. the return type is `void`) but you attempt to use the return value.  The function should be changed to have a return type of `int` and you need to `return sum`.
- The parameters `a` and `b` that `sum` expects are shadowed by local variables called `a` and `b`.  This means the parameters are never used.  Since you have nothing to pass in anyway, just remove the parameters.

After applying these fixes, your program will look like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum();

int sum()
{
    int a,b;
    int sum;
    cout<<"Enter Two numbers "<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    sum=a+b;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int z=sum();
    cout<<"Sum is "<<z<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows and learn more [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-program-to-add-two-numbers/) about adding functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int, int);

int main()
{
   int num1, num2, x;
   cout<<"Enter two integer numbers: ";
   cin>>num1>>num2;
   //This will call the first function
   cout<<"Result: "<<sum(num1, num2)<< endl;
   return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{
   return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

because there is no return in your function.
if you want to save the result in a new variable you have to make a return 1)
or you just safe it as a already existing variable 2)

1)

```
int sum(int a,int b)
{
    int a,b;
    int sum;
    cout<<"Enter Two numbers "<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    sum=a+b;
    return sum_ab;
}
```

2. 

```
void sum(int a,int b)
{
    int a,b;
    int sum;
    cout<<"Enter Two numbers "<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    a=a+b;
}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to use a new variable `sum_ab` instead of the already existing `sum`? Besides that `sum_ab` is not declared anywhere and nothing is assigned to it. And for **2** why should it be better so save it in `a` then in `sum`? For your shown code it would make any difference.

Comment: ja sorry, you are right! i were faster in writing than in thinking. will answer next time proper

Comment: `will answer next time proper` you should correct the answer using the [edit].